# r: How to make a function return two plot objects arranged by par()

Tags: r, function, plot

So I am new to `functions` and I am trying to create a simple `function` that returns two plots arranged by `par()`, like

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(5,5,2,2))
hist(p$vitd,  col='lightgray', prob=T)
lines(density(p$vitd), lwd=2)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(p$vitd), sd=sd(p$vitd)), 
      col="red", lwd=2, add=TRUE)
qqnorm(p$vitd) 
qqline(p$vitd)
```

Giving the expected output:
[image]

So I can only figure out how to return one object

Like

```
norm_f <- function(y){
  
list(qqnorm(y),qqline(y))
  
}

norm_f(p$vitd)
```

#or

```
norm_f <- function(y){
  
list(hist(y,  col='lightgray', prob=T),
     lines(density(y), lwd=2),
     curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(y), sd=sd(y)), 
           col="red", lwd=2, add=TRUE))
  
}

norm_f(p$vitd)
```

I tried `return(list(), list())`- but that did not work.

**Question:** how can I make the `function` return the two plot objects?

Also, when running `norm_f(p$vitd)`, the `function` automatically prints a lot of text in the `Console` - how can I get rid of that?

Data

```
p <- structure(list(vitd = c(28.5, 32.9, 60.3, 50.5, 15, 47.8, 78.7, 
16.3, 71.9, 32.1, 33.2, 20.3, 33.5, 25.3, 89.8, 39.8, 27.6, 15.1, 
61.8, 50.8, 72.1, 13.1, 18.3, 67.1, 60.2, 53.7, 54.6, 11.4, 48.5, 
78.1, 29.1, 55.4, 75.1, 69.3, 91.2, 19.7, 26.9, 54.5, 25, 84.4, 
15.6, 76.6, 45, 39.4, 67.6, 53.9, 93.6, 43.9, 25.8, 49.6, 46.1, 
46.5, 57.3, 61.4, 29.8, 67.8, 64.4, 59.4, 44, 58.8, 5.2, 23.8, 
26.7, 42.3, 19.9, 72.4, 54.2, 69.5, 70.1, 22.1, 46.3, 52.2, 61.7, 
50.7, 46.9, 28, 29.4, 29.7, 72.4, 96.6, 55.5, 36.2, 36.2, 61.8, 
76.7, 43.5, 41.9, 76.8, 90, 44.4, 33, 46, 28.2, 47.7, 40.7, 41.4, 
53.2, 53.9, 35.3, 14.9)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Base graphics functions don't typically return a graphic object: the plotting portion is a *side-effect* of calling the function. Many plotting functions return a (non-graphics) object that can be used to regenerate the plot, and/or it includes good-to-know information about the processing (e.g., `legend` returns its bounding box). Additionally, one can only return a single "thing" from a function; often, when heterogeneous data is returned, it's as a named list. What is it that you need the returned graphic objects to be used as?

Comment: Hi @r2evans - thank you for your input. Simply trying to learn something about `functions`. My intention here is to produce a function to obtain a quick overview of the covariate follows a normal distribution. `norm_f(p$vitd)` returns a graph when running it.

Comment: It's not *returning* a graph, it's *producing* a plot in side-effect. Feel free to have a `list` of the return objects of each of the graphics functions, but realize that they are not consistent, and some are just `NULL`. Again, what are you hoping to do with this returned value?

Comment: I aim to write a function `norm_f(x)` that produces two plots of `x` (the `histogram` and `qq-plot` described above). Can this be done?

Comment: Writing a function that *produces* two plots is completely different from the concept of *returning* two plots. Using base graphics, the latter is not possible, but the former most certainly is. Your premise of "functions" is correct, but your assumption that R base graphic functions return a "plot" is not. Most base graphics functions *do not return a plot*; if they return anything, that "thing" *might* be something that can be reused to regenerate a plot, but that is neither the norm nor is it the same thing.

Comment: As an example, `h <- hist(mtcars$disp)` returns a named list with several components that can be used to regenerate the plot. In order to regenerate the histogram from `h`, one would do `plot(h)`, but not only is that not the same thing (since it is not a stored "plot" object), also the plot looks different (the argument defaults are different).

Comment: In base R graphics, there is the concept of `recordPlot`, but still that is not what you are trying to do (nor do I encourage necessarily trying to warp it to do what you are trying to do).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. So if it is possible to write the `norm_f(x)` function which produce the two base-R graphics described above, how should I proceed or can you write me an example? Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```r
norm_f <- function(z, hist. = list(col = "lightgray"),
                   lines. = list(lwd = 2), curve. = list(col = "red", lwd = 2),
                   qqnorm. = list(col = "gray70", pch = 16, cex = 0.5), qqline. = list(lwd = 2)) {
  zname <- deparse(substitute(z))
  zden <- density(z)
  if (!"ylim" %in% names(hist.)) {
    ymax <- max(zden$y, dnorm(c(seq(min(z), max(z), len = 21)), mean = mean(z), sd = sd(z)))
    hist.$ylim <- c(0, ymax)
  }
  par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(5,5,2,2))
  if (!"main" %in% names(hist.)) hist.$main <- paste("Histogram of", zname)
  if (!"xlab" %in% names(hist.)) hist.$xlab <- zname
  do.call(hist, c(list(z,  prob = TRUE), hist.))
  do.call(lines, c(list(zden), lines.))
  do.call(curve, c(list(substitute(dnorm(x, mean=mean(z), sd=sd(z))),
                        add = TRUE), curve.))
  do.call(qqnorm, c(list(z), qqnorm.))
  do.call(qqline, c(list(z), qqline.))
}

norm_f(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

[image: sample side-by-side plot]