# How to incorporate visualization of log2-transformation in function?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, plot

I have this `norm_f()` function with help from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998795/r-how-to-make-a-function-return-two-plot-objects-arranged-by-par). The function produces two plots to assess the normal distribution:

```
> norm_f(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

[image]

The function is written with:

```
norm_f <- function(z, hist. = list(col = "lightgray"),
                   lines. = list(lwd = 2), curve. = list(col = "red", lwd = 2),
                   qqnorm. = list(col = "black", pch = 1, cex = 1.2), qqline. = list(lwd = 2)) {
  zname <- deparse(substitute(z))
  zden <- density(z)
  if (!"ylim" %in% names(hist.)) {
    ymax <- max(zden$y, dnorm(c(seq(min(z), max(z), len = 21)), mean = mean(z), sd = sd(z)))
    hist.$ylim <- c(0, ymax)
  }
  par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(5,5,2,2))
  if (!"main" %in% names(hist.)) hist.$main <- paste("Histogram of", zname)
  if (!"xlab" %in% names(hist.)) hist.$xlab <- zname
  do.call(hist, c(list(z,  prob = TRUE), hist.))
  do.call(lines, c(list(zden), lines.))
  do.call(curve, c(list(substitute(dnorm(x, mean=mean(z), sd=sd(z))),
                        add = TRUE), curve.))
  do.call(qqnorm, c(list(z), qqnorm.))
  do.call(qqline, c(list(z), qqline.))
  
}
```

I want to update the function, so that it produces 2x2 plots: two without log2-transformation (as above) and two plots with log2-tansformation of the covariate (i.e., corresponding to `norm_f(log2(iris$Sepal.Length))`)

**Expected output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the original function `norm_f()` to work with **ggplot2** and **patchwork**. Now the function takes three arguments: `df` which is your data.frame, `var` which is a character representing your target variable (e.g., `Sepal.Length`) and `thefun` which calls the scaling function you want without quotes. The plots are rendered through **ggplot2** and their layout is organized via **patchwork**.

Please, have a look at the code below to check if it fits your needs. I run two examples, one with the requested `log2()` function and the second one with `exp()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

data(iris)

norm_f <- function( df, var, thefun, ... ) {
  
  # this gets the name of the function invoked
  fun_name = as.character(match.call()[4]) 
  # this matches the function in `thefun` so that you can use it
  thefun = match.fun(thefun)
  
  # compute the log2
  va2_log2 <- thefun(df[ , var ])
  
  # specify we want the density for the histogram
  y <- "..density.."
  # Histogram of "var"
  p_hist <- ggplot( df, aes_string(x = var) ) +
    geom_histogram(aes_string( y = y ) ) + 
    geom_density() +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
                  args = list(mean = mean(df[ , var ], na.rm = TRUE), 
                              sd = sd(df[ , var ], na.rm = TRUE)), 
                  colour = 'blue') + 
    ggtitle(paste0("Histogram of ", var) )
  
  # QQ-plot of "var"
  p_qq <- ggplot( df, aes_string(sample = var) ) +
    stat_qq() + stat_qq_line() +
    ggtitle(paste0("QQ-Plot of ", var) )
  
  # Histogram of log2("var")
  p_hist_log <- ggplot( df, aes_string(x = va2_log2) ) +
    geom_histogram(aes_string( y = y ) ) + 
    geom_density() +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
                  args = list(mean = mean(va2_log2, na.rm = TRUE), 
                              sd = sd(va2_log2, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                  colour = 'blue') +
    ggtitle( paste0("Histogram of ", fun_name, "(", var, ")" ) )
  
  # QQ-plot of log2("var")
  p_qq_log <- ggplot( df, aes_string(sample = va2_log2) ) +
    stat_qq() + stat_qq_line() +
    ggtitle( paste0("QQ-Plot of ", fun_name, "(", var, ")" ) )
  
  print((p_hist + p_qq) / (p_hist_log + p_qq_log))
  
}

norm_f(df = iris, var = "Sepal.Length", thefun = log2 )
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
norm_f(df = iris, var = "Sepal.Length", thefun = exp )
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @FrancescoGrosetti. Thank you very much, nice solution. I like the idea of specifying arguments. Spin-off question: would it be possible to add a `log`-argument, that takes the values `2`, `10` and `ln`(default `2`), so that `norm_f` produces the non-transformed `histogram` + `QQ plot` and the log-transformed `histogram` and `QQ plot` depending on the `log=2,10 or ln`?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated response. This should do the job.